# How to change a value inside a nested NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uitextfield, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `textfield` dynamically generated and it is added in to an mutable array named `field`:

```
[field addObject:textfield];
```

`textfield` contains all the properties of the `textfield` (like placeholder etc...).

Now I have a mutable dictionary with a key-value pair like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[m setObject:@{} forKey:@"V"];
```

Now what I want to achieve is that I want to change the value of `m.V[field[i].placeholder]` with the value `@"abc"`. It is inside a `for` loop.

What I want is that to add a value corresponding to field[i].placeholder key.

I dont know how to write the above code.

Can anyone please help? I hope the question is clear.

EDIT:

```
for(UITextField *f in field){
    [[m objectforkey:@"V"] setobject:@"abc" forkey:@"placeholder"];
}
```

This is what i am trying to achieve.But it shows error.

Comment: it is not really clear what your `m` dictionary really holds fro key `"V"`, and how that object is connected to your `textfield` or `field`.

Comment: @holex question edited...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *suspect* the issue is that the inner dictionary is immutable as you have used the newer Objective-C literal syntax.  Instead, create the dictionary with the following code, which explicitly creates an inner mutable dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *inner = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"value1", @"key1",
    @"value2", @"key2",
    nil];
[m setObject:inner forKey:@"V"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I guess this is the answer for your question.

```
for (UITextField *textfield in [m valueForKey: @"V"]){

textField.placeholder = @"abc";

}
```